# How to use Test.setCreatedDate method with a list

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm getting this error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setCreatedDate(List<Object__c>, Datetime)

With this (excerpt of) test class below

```java
List<Object__c> testRecords = new List<Object__c>();

for (Integer i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    testRecords.add(new Object__c(Name = 'Test Record ' + i));
    DateTime TestCreatedDate = DateTime.now().addDays(-15);
    Test.setCreatedDate(testRecords, TestCreatedDate);
}

insert testRecords;
```

No problem doing it with a single record Id, but no idea how to do it with a list. This is to test a class that deletes records more than 14 days old (which is working). The test class saves if I remove the `Test.setCreatedDate()` method, but then the test doesn't pass.

I've omitted the entire class for the sake of not having to redact a bunch of org specific information, but if it's a necessity then I'll begrudgingly amend it for public consumption...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says there's only `setCreatedDate(Id recordId, Datetime createdDatetime)`, so you've gotta do this one record at a time

- Create your test records
- Insert them
- Iterate over your test records and call `Test.setCreatedDate()`

```java
List<Object__c> testRecords = new List<Object__c>();

// Since this is a constant, it should be declared/initialized outside of all loops
DateTime testCreatedDate = DateTime.now().addDays(-15);

// Create records
for (Integer i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    testRecords.add(new Object__c(Name = 'Test Record ' + i));
}

insert testRecords;

// Set the date
for(Object__c testObj :testRecords){
    Test.setCreatedDate(testObj.Id, testCreatedDate);
}
```

Comment: Derek, you're a gentleman and a scholar. That worked!

If there's a way of marking a correct answer, I can't find it...

Comment: @Gaffers There's a checkmark under the vote section (the up and down arrows). I don't remember if there's a minimum time that you need to wait before accepting an answer though (I answer more questions than I ask).